# Invalid left hand side in argument - Reference error

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, c3.js

I have a simple javascript function where I loop through a series. I then push a value to an array and then assign it to an object. I am doing this for creating a c3 combination chart.

It shows a simple error **"message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment",**.

> JavaScript Function

```js
//COMBINATION STARTS HERE-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    this._initialize_settings_Combination = function () {
    
        if (!this.isCombinationChart()) return;

        this._resultSettingsJ.data.types = {};
        var _types = [];

       
        var _series = this.Serieses();

        
        for (var _count = 1; _count < this.seriesCount; _count++) { 
            debugger;
            _types.push(_series(_count).chartType);
            this._resultSettingsJ.data.types.dataSeries + '_count' = _types[_count].value;             
        }

        

    }
```

I think it happens because of the way I assigned my object to array value. I am not sure. I searched a lot for this solution but I can't find it. I know it is simple error but it would be greatly helpful if someone helped me.

Comment: please add an example of the wanted target.

Comment: for (var _count = 1; _count < this.seriesCount; _count++) { 
     
            _types.push(_series(1).bar);
            this._resultSettingsJ.data.types.dataSeries + '1' = _types[_count].bar;             
        }     //this._resultSettingsJ.data.types.dataSeries1 = 'bar'   This is the expected result  @NinaScholz

Answer (score 1):

You could take a bracket notation as [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors),

> ```
> object.property    // dot notation
> object['property'] // bracket notation
> ```

where you could use a combined key.

By using dot notation, you need a single constant a propery.

```
this._resultSettingsJ.data.types['dataSeries' + _count] = _types[_count].value;
```

Comment: I am hardcoding 'dataSeries' and  I need it to return like this ---->this._resultSettingsJ.data.types.dataSeries1  = _types[1].value . Will the above code work for this to work? @NinaScholz

Comment: The error is resolved thanks to you! But I can't check if the value returned is correct. I need to get user input which I don't have. I just need to know if this will return the result i need which is 'this._resultSettingsJ.data.types.dataSeries1 = _types[1].value ' @NinaScholz

Comment: you could check the value of `_types[_count].value` in advance and assign only if valid.

Comment: ok. But will I get left side correct like this ''this._resultSettingsJ.data.types.dataSeries1' . @NinaScholz

Comment: " this._resultSettingsJ.data.types.dataSeries1 " This is my expected result. ".......types['dataSeries' + _count] " Using [] will result in dataseries1 but i cant call it as a property of object (this._resultSettingsJ.data.types) using ' . ' operator. I amybe wrong .. @NinaScholz